# Теряются данные при передаче через POST

Tags: php, .htaccess

Передаю данные из `adminpanel.php` в `auth.php` посредством POST.
До `auth.php` данные не доходят. Проверил на сервере без `.htaccess` - там всё работает.
Вроде как дело в этом - `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`, но если убрать эту строчку, все страницы, кроме главной, благополучно превращаются в `404`, подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся.

Содержимое:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options All -Indexes

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extension less url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extension-less php urls
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Disables page caching for real-time updating

FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"


# Compatibility: Rewrite URLs
Redirect "/nightly" "/compatibility?b"
Redirect "/builds" "/compatibility?b"
Redirect "/compat" "/compatibility"
Redirect "/library" "/compatibility?l"

# Assigns an error page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
```

Comment: Такой вид не пробовали?     RewriteRule  ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Пробовал, уходит в циклический редирект.

Comment: поставь секцию резолва выше чем редирект на безэкстеншен

Comment: Сработало, благодарю.